# Can not save xml file using minidom

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I tried to modify and save a xml file using minidom in python.

Everything is quite working good except 1 specific file, that I only can read but can not write it back.

Code that I use to save xml file:

```
domXMLFile = minidom.parse(dom_document_filename)

#some modification

F= open(dom_document_filename,"w")
domXMLFile .writexml(F)
F.close()
```

My question is :
**Is it true that minidom can not handle too large file ( 714KB )?**

How do i solve my problem?

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: It does not throw any error that I can dig in. Just crash!

Or is there any way that I know what is the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, `lxml` is way better than `minidom` for handling XML. If you have it, here is how to use it:

```
from lxml import etree 
root = etree.parse('path/file.xml')

# some changes to root

with open('path/file.xml', 'w') as f:
     f.write(etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True))
```

If not, you could use `pdb` to debug your code. Just write `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` in your code where you want a break pont and when running your function in a shell, it should stop at this line. It may give you a better view for what is not working.

Comment: Thank you, this is the thing im looking for.
Its working fine now.

Comment: Thank you! Just in case if someone is facing problem with converting `bytes` to `str`, I had to add `.decode('utf-8')` at the end of `etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True)` to convert it from `byte` to `str`.